# Continuous in $I\times J$ - then continuous in $I$ and in $J$?

Tags: continuity

Maybe it is a silly question, but:

> > If I have a function $f$ that is continuous on $I\times J\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$; does this imply that $f$ is continuous in $I$ and in $J$?

My intuitive answer is: Yes, of course, because if one looks at the criterion of continuity that uses series, i.e.

$$
(x_k,y_k)\to (x,y)\Rightarrow f((x_k,y_k))\to f((x,y))
$$

that implies

$$
x_k\to x\Rightarrow f(x_k)\to f(x)
$$

respectively

$$
y_k\to y\Rightarrow f(y_k)\to f(y).
$$

Or am I totally wrong and confused?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by continuous on $I$ or $J$? The function is defined on $I \times J$.

Comment: You probably mean that, fixed $y\in J$, the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous on $I$ and similarly fixing the other variable. This is true and the reasoning you present is substantially correct, but must be fixed.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant respectively wanted to say. Of course it is necessary to define new functions for that, because, as copper.hat said, $f$ itself is defined on $I\times J$.

Comment: Maybe you should also see the definitions of 'separate continuity' and 'joint continuity'. If $f$ is (jointly) continuous in $I\times J$, then $f$ is separately continuous, i.e., $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous in $J$ for each fixed $x\in I$ and $f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous in $I$ for each fixed $y\in J$. However, the converse is not true!

Comment: Do you mean "see" or "say"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that the functions $i_y: I \to I \times J$ and $j_x: J \to I \times J$ defined by $i_y(x) = (x,y)$ and $j_x(y) = (x,y)$ are continuous. Hence the functions $f \circ i_y$, $f \circ j_x$ will be contiinuous.